# Non-Async Method In Async Call Stack

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Sorry for a terrible title, I just wanted to confirm that I am making the correct assumptions.

Say I have 3 methods that are simplified to:

```
public async Task Method1()
{ 
    var obj = await Method2();
    //do work on obj
} 

public Task<object> Method2()
{
    //do some work
    return Method3();     
}

public async Task<object> Method3()
{
    //do async work
    return obj;
}
```

`Method2` above does no async work internally, but is in my async stack.  It could be rewritten as:

```
public async Task<object> Method2()
{
    //do some work
    return await Method3();
}
```

Am I correct that, as `Method2` doesn't actually do async work, that it is better to leave it as a non-async method?  My thought is that I'm saving the overhead of creating an extra state machine to hold the thread's resources when it is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct. You can return the `Task` directly from a method without adding the `async/await` keywords if the method does not need to await any result (ie. consume the result of a task or wait for a task to complete to be able to do some execution). That returned Task can then be awaited by a caller further down the call stack. This can save a little overhead and make for **slightly** less code (*although that amount of code is actually trivial*).

You often see this with pass through or convenience methods.